# c# wpf DataGridCell set value from convertor

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have this DataGridCell and it calls this converter. I was expecting the value of this cell to be "hi" (as I'm setting the cell "content" to "hi") when its shown in the datagrid after going through the convertor.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Google" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Current Position on Google" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseUp" Handler="IdUnselect"/>

            <Setter Property="Background"   Value="{Binding GoogleKeywordPositionMovementSinceLastWeekCheck, Converter={StaticResource NameToBrushConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content"      Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GooglePositionConvertor}}"/>

        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>

</DataGridTextColumn>



public class GooglePositionConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ResultCheckObject RankCheck = value as ResultCheckObject;

        return "hi";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You bind to current source Path=., but what is your current source!? and in converter you cast value to ResultCheckObject but return just 'Hi' why are  then casting that value if you dont use it?

Comment: How do I set the content/text of the datagrid cell through a converter?

Comment: For example, you could have some property int that data contex to bind onto, then that property value will go through convertor and return back

Comment: figured it out now, needed to set it in DataGridTextColumn  as opposed to using <Setter Property="Content" Value="whatever">

Answer (score 0):

Setting the content through a converter in the way below did not work.

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GooglePositionConvertor}}"/>
```

Setting it through a converter as below worked

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Google" Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GooglePositionConvertor}}" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True">
```